# Cannot print array of strings without getting garbage characters

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *test[5][20];
    char *input[20];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){

    printf("enter> ");
    fflush ( stdout );
    fgets(input,20,stdin);
         *test[i] = *input;
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
       printf("%d | %s\n",i,test[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> enter> pwd
>
> enter> pathd
>
> enter> ls
>
> enter> echo $path
>
> enter> pwd 0 | pwd
>
> 1 | path▒] a▒▒a▒▒#a▒▒ 2 | ls
>
> 3 | echo▒▒( 4 | pwd
>
> Press [Enter] to close the terminal
>   ...

I also need to be able to read in input that has spaces.  Thanks!

Comment: Showing how `test` is declared might be helpful

Comment: @ArunSaha, `char *test[5][20];`

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: Ok I tagged it.  My primary language is Java i am not looking for someone to solve my homework as this is but a small portion of it and i just don't get it.

Comment: you can see how test is declared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `memcpy()`. And you need to strip trailing newlines. Here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void chopnl(char *s) {              //strip '\n'
    s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char test[5][20];
    char input[20];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("enter> ");
        fflush ( stdout );
        fgets(input, 20, stdin);
        chopnl(input);
        memcpy(test[i], input, strlen(input)+1);//test[i] = input;
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
       printf("%d | %s\n",i,test[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...one question why strlen(input)+1?

Comment: The third argument in `memcpy()` is the number of bytes to copy. And since `strlen()` returns the actual length of a string, it doesn't include the null terminator `\0`, so you have to allocate space for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your types are all messed up. A string in C is essentially a pointer to a character which begins a sequence of characters that ends with a null byte.

Input is an array of pointers to characters--or in this purpose, an array of strings. What you're doing is reading 20 characters into input, where input in that fgets expression acts as the address of the first element of the array. So you're reading 20 characters from stdin into input's 20 pointers to characters. This is not what you want. You want to read the characters into space for a string.

I assume you are compiling using GCC--consider using -Wall so GCC warns you about the type issues.

Another issue is

```
*test[i] = *input;
```

Since this seems like homework, I feel like I have given enough details.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is answered and is very old, but the accepted solution is actually wrong. If you enter more than 19 characters `stdin` will be left with bytes that will be read on the next fgets() and it will find the newline and the next entry will be incorrect.

See the following code and notice a few things:

-- You don't need a separate buffer to read your input into. Just read directly into the array.

-- After reading into the array, remove the `'\n'`

-- If need be, flush `stdin`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char test[5][20+1] = {{0}};     // extra space for NULL
    int i;
    int c;
    char *ptr = NULL;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("enter> ");
        fgets(test[i], 20+1, stdin);    // fgets read n-1 characters so we add 1 since our buffer has space for null already
        if( (ptr = strrchr(test[i], '\n') ) )
        {
            *ptr = 0x00;
        }
        else
        {
            // need to flush stdin since '\n' wasn't found fgets() didn't read all of input
            while( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF );       
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
       printf("%d | %s\n",i,test[i]);

    return 0;
}
```